# Graphics2D rotate before saving file

Tags: java, graphics2d

I create this image with g2d:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(408, 408, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);    
Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
List<Pixel> pixels = cacheRepo.findAll();
pixels.stream().forEach(pixel -> {
    g2d.setColor(getColorFromPixel(pixel));
    g2d.fillRect(getPos(pixel.getPosition().x), getPos(pixel.getPosition().y), 20, 20);
});
```

Now I am trying to rotate it 90° anticlok so that the bleu square appear on the lower left:

[image]

So I add this:

```
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
g2d.drawRenderedImage(bufferedImage, null);
```

But the rotation doesn't occur (I still have the same image).

Here is the complete piece of code, with the part that save image:

```
 // Constructs a BufferedImage of one of the predefined image types.
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(408, 408, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    // Create a graphics which can be used to draw into the buffered image
    Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    List<Pixel> pixels = cacheRepo.findAll();
    pixels.stream().forEach(pixel -> {
        g2d.setColor(getColorFromPixel(pixel));
        g2d.fillRect(getPos(pixel.getPosition().x), getPos(pixel.getPosition().y), 20, 20);
    });
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
    g2d.drawRenderedImage(bufferedImage, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    // Save as PNG
    File file = new File("myimage.png");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformations should be applied BEFORE any operations you want to be effected by them, transformations won't affect anything that was done before it...

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(408, 408, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
// Create a graphics which can be used to draw into the buffered image
Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
List<Pixel> pixels = cacheRepo.findAll();
pixels.stream().forEach(pixel -> {
    g2d.setColor(getColorFromPixel(pixel));
    g2d.fillRect(getPos(pixel.getPosition().x), getPos(pixel.getPosition().y), 20, 20);
});
//g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
// Not sure what you're hoping to achieve here
//g2d.drawRenderedImage(bufferedImage, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

If you prefer, use two `BufferedImages`.  Render the "normal" content to the first, then use the second to paint the first, but with a rotation transformation ... because transformations do my head in

> using your code draw a black image

You probably need to supply a anchor point around which the image can be rotated, otherwise it will be rated about the top/left corner

And you'll forgive me, but it's not like this kind of think hasn't been asked before

- [Java rotate image turns part of background black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143111/java-rotate-image-turns-part-of-background-black/34144190#34144190)
- [Rotate a buffered image in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758061/rotate-a-buffered-image-in-java/37758533#37758533)
- [Rotating Image with AffineTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275424/rotating-image-with-affinetransform/20280225#20280225)
- [Rotating an Image object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204114/rotating-an-image-object/30204975#30204975)
- [I'm rotating image in java but want to save rotated image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799392/im-rotating-image-in-java-but-want-to-save-rotated-image/44813062#44813062)
- [How to save rotated buffered image in another buffered image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395716/how-to-save-rotated-buffered-image-in-another-buffered-image/36395888#36395888)
- [BufferedImage rotated, change resulting background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256183/bufferedimage-rotated-change-resulting-background/20256348#20256348)

Comment: using your code draw a black image :(... I want to give a try with the "two BufferedImage", but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: So, two things.  You should specify a anchor point around which the rotation should occur - I prefer the centre as it's the easiest to resolve; second, I don't know why you're manually copying the pixels, I'd just use `Graphcis2D.drawImage`